# SSL certificate configuration is rejected by Firefox

Tags: ssl, firefox

I am trying to get a secure website work over SSL. Since the site is used only by company employees, it's SSL certificate is emitted by our sysadmin, based on home-produced CA root certificate (via intermediate CA certificate). So, technically, it's authenticity can not be verified, one has to trust that the root certificate is really issued by reliable entity.

I am testing the site on Ubuntu 14.04, using Firefox and Chromium web browsers.

It was expected that it would be enough to import the root, intermediate and site certificates in Firefox (Preferences/Advances/Certificates), to make the site work. However, I get this sec_error_untrusted_cert error: "The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified."

On Chromium, it was enough to import the self-cooked intermediate CA (Settings/Show advanced settings/Manage certificates/Authorities) to make the browser open the site without complaints.

Internet Explorer (on Windows) also opens the side without complaints, when the certificates are imported.

So, how to make the Firefox accept the self-cooked certificates? I know it wants me to protect from malicious, unverified certificates, but in this case I am aware of the issuer and want to trust it.

Comment: It should be enough to import the root (*just* the root) CA certificate into the browser's trust store, tick the "websites" box, and then properly configure the server to present the intermediate with the end-entity certificate. Beyond that, more diagnostic information is required. The output of an `openssl s_client` session is my usual first step.

Comment: Meh, this turns out to be some short-lived bug that was introduced with the new, stricter FF version. After update and certification deleting+reimporting, the site opens fine.